# Why does this script work? (and other questions) [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html

To begin I would like to say that I am new to javascript. VERY new.

The questions I have is regarding this simple (googled) script:

```
window.onload = function(){
    bobby();
        function bobby(){
            document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "Hello World"
        }
    }
```

Of course I know WHAT it does (it puts the string "Hello World" in the element which has an ID of 'print'), and it works too. However I have no clue WHY it works.
If I were to use-

```
window.onload = function(){
        function bobby(){
            document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "Hello World"
        }
    }
```

or-

```
window.onload = bobby(){
    function bobby() {
        document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

instead, it won't work despite it looking like it should (to a freshman like me).

My questions are these: what is going on behind the scenes? What is going wrong / what is going right? Is there anything obsolete/missing in the scripts above? What should I keep an eye out for? Why does it first need to be a function, why can't I only use the line that actually executes the script?

Comment: https://javascript.info/first-steps

Comment: The first snippet works because `bobby()` is not only declared, but also invoked, in contrast to the other snippets

Comment: Just for clarity, while Nico Haase's comment answers your question generally it's not considered good practice to invoke a function before you've declared it (which works only because of [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)). In other words, that code snippet you found isn't very good.

Comment: Glad to see all the responses thank you all :) And thanks for pointing out why it isn't a good snippet Jared Smith, every little bit helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tackle why this code works:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    bobby();
        function bobby(){
            document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "Hello World"
        }
    }
```

#### windows.onload

You can assign a function to the `windows.onload` and in some point (when de browser finish to load the resource) it will be called, something like `windows.onload()`

In  you case `windows.onload()` is going to execute the anonymous function with this code:

```js
function()
{ // from here
    bobby();
        function bobby(){
            document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "Hello World"
        }
    
} // to here
```

in your second snippet when when the code runs only declare a function but never runs.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

#### Function bobby and  and bobby call

consider now the function expression

```js
function(){
    bobby();
    function bobby(){
         // some code
    }
}
```

I suspect that you are wondering why the function call is before the function declaration

When a function is declared like bobby in the snippet the javascript compiler move the declaration to the beginning of the scope ([hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)), so when the code runs is running like this:

```js
function(){ // <-function scope beginning
    function bobby(){
         // some code
    }

    bobby();
}// <-function scope end
```

But this is only that way in functions declaration and not in function expressions. consider this:

```js
function(){
    bobby();
    bobby2();
    function bobby(){ // some code}
    let bobby2 = function(){ // some code}
}
```

after compilation will look like this:

```js
function(){
    function bobby(){ // some code}
    let bobby2;

    bobby(); // works
    bobby2(); // fails because bobby2 is not a function (yet)

    bobby2 = function(){ // some code}
}
```

Hope it helps to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In the first peace of code (that works) you are declaring a function ("function bobby()...") and executing it "bobby();" And all this is executed by anonymous function that runs on onload window event.
The second piece of code only declares function bobby().
The third one something I am not familiar with, but it looks like you are executing function bobby() and inside of it there is a declaration of an inner function bobby()